# embed.add_field invalid syntax error discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKEmn.png)

```
if message.content.startswith('/help'):
    await message.delete()
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Help",url="https://discord.com/channels/1138190037234749522/1139129893884547113",
    description="This should probably help you and starting players with everything they need to know about this server and what it can do.\nThis is also made in 10/08/2023 14:34 so do not expect this to contain everything that is needed and this will probably be outdated.\n\nPlease read the Quick Rules first.",
    colour=0xd7f736,
    embed.set_author(name="Invadtrix",
    url="https://discord.gg/G76wVADr8H",
    icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/1139112081073918002.webp?size=128&quality=lossless")
    embed.add_field(name="Quick Rules",
    value="1. No Toxicity\n2. Respect everyone\n3. Don't be racist\n4. No NSFW in any channel\n5. Please don't break any\nRule\n6. Listen to moderators\n7. If you find anyone\nbreaking the rules:\nPlease contact a moderator\nor higher about them",
    inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Help",
    value="This wont tell you everything\nBut the Guide channel will\n------------------------------------\nIn the scripts channel you can get the scripts\nfor the games you play (Not all)\nThe bot channel is for bot commands\nIts the only channel where you can use bot commands\nGeneral already explains it\nBut if you don't understand: Its basically a place where you can talk with other people",
    inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Commands",
    value="This will not contain everything.\n\n/Help   /Commands   /Scripts   /Guide   /Announcements \nThat's all for now.\nFor more commands go to the commands channel or say \"/Commands\"\nthey both are the same and will always be.",
    inline=True)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/1139112081073918002.webp?size=128&quality=lossless")

    embed.set_footer(text="Thank you")

    await message.author.send(embed=embed)
```

I tried fixing something but that didn't work
and I  was expecting for it to work but I guess I was wrong :c
The first error was at Line 52

Comment: Can you please also add the error message?

Comment: i hope this helps
sorry for the late response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So uhh I found out the problem

In the discord embed creator I enabled timestamps
For some reason the timestamps did not work
So I decided to remove the timestamps from the code..
And I umm... You will see for yourself

[with timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LylgT.png)

[without timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUHuX.png)

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZlu3.png)